# Why doesn't my combobox macro work when the input range is a string?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I want different macros to run when different items are selected in my Excel sheet combobox. This works perfectly fine when the input range is an integer (see VBA code below).

```
Sub Hide_Charts_Combobox()
'
' Hide_Charts_Combobox
'
    Dim X As ControlFormat
    Set X = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Drop Down 95").ControlFormat
    If X = 1 Then
    Hide_Matrix
    ElseIf X = 2 Then
    Hide_Radar
    ElseIf X = 3 Then
    Hide_Goal_Ranks
    ElseIf X = 4 Then
    Hide_Goal_Ranks_bd
    ElseIf X = 5 Then
    Hide_KPI_Values
    ElseIf X = 6 Then
    Hide_Goal_Ratio
    ElseIf X = 7 Then
    Hide_KPI_Ratio
    ElseIf X = 8 Then
    Hide_Unitized_Ratio
    End If
'
End Sub
```

However, I don't want my combobox input range to be numbers; I want certain words instead. When I replace the inputs by strings, the macro simply does not run (no errors appear either). This is the actual code I want to use (and which is currently not working):

```
Sub Hide_Charts_Combobox()
'
' Hide_Charts_Combobox
'
    Dim X As ControlFormat
    Set X = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Drop Down 95").ControlFormat
    If X = Matrix Then
    Hide_Matrix
    ElseIf X = Radar Then
    Hide_Radar
    ElseIf X = Goal Ranks Then
    Hide_Goal_Ranks
    ElseIf X = Goal Breakdown Then
    Hide_Goal_Ranks_bd
    ElseIf X = KPI Values Then
    Hide_KPI_Values
    ElseIf X = Goal Ratios Then
    Hide_Goal_Ratio
    ElseIf X = KPI Ratios Then
    Hide_KPI_Ratio
    ElseIf X = Unitized Ratios Then
    Hide_Unitized_Ratio
    End If
'
End Sub
```

I suspect it has something to do with Dim X being defined as a ControlFormat which cannot hold a string, but I'm not sure. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: If you add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module, it'll cause errors at run time when it sees undeclared variables (Variables without a `Dim` line). This can be helpful for catching things like typos, or forgetting the quotation marks for strings, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Replace:

```
 If X = Matrix Then
```

with

```
 If X = "Matrix" Then
```

etc.

Comment: I haven't been able to get the drop down selected value, to be compared to a string, from `Set X = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Drop Down 95").ControlFormat`. How did you?

Answer (score 3):

I really hate adding a new answer when Gary summed it up well, but just to add another option for the sake of improved readability, `Select Case` would work well here.

```
Select Case X
Case "Matrix"
    Hide_Matrix
Case "Radar"
    Hide_Radar
Case "Goal Ranks"
    Hide_Goal_Ranks
Case "Goal Breakdown"
    Hide_Goal_Ranks_bd
Case "KPI Values"
    Hide_KPI_Values
Case "Goal Ratios"
    Hide_Goal_Ratio
Case "KPI Ratios"
    Hide_KPI_Ratio
Case "Unitized Ratios"
    Hide_Unitized_Ratio
End Select
```

`Select Case` works well for readability because you are comparing the *same variable*, where you can quickly gather by looking at the case that each one is referring to `x`.

In an `If...Then` statement, you have to read line-by-line, thus making you read more and also having an increased chance for errors.

Answer (score 3):

you could use `Application.Run` method and feed it with chosen sub name taken from drop down *input range* (obtained from `ControlFormat` `ListFillRange` property) selected cell (obtained from `ControlFormat` `ListIndex` property):

```
Sub Hide_Charts_Combobox()
    Dim X As ControlFormat
    Set X = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Drop Down 95").ControlFormat

    Application.Run "Hide_" & Range(X.ListFillRange).Offset(X.ListIndex - 1).Resize(1).Value
End Sub
```